# How to avoid similar rows during excel import with django-import-export?

Tags: python-3.x, django, excel, django-import-export

I have an excel file that has multiple rows which contain similar data. For example employee name is repeated in multiple rows but i would like to import such records only once and not multiple times into my database to avoid redundancy. I have seen that skip_rows method may help with this but still cannot figure how exactly to use it since the documentation is very limited. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to keep a list of already imported values (based on some identifier), and then override `skip_row()` to ignore any duplicates.

For example:

```py
class _BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    imported_names = set()

    def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        self.imported_names.add(row.get("name"))

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        return instance.name in self.imported_names

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'author_email', 'price')
```

Then running this will skip any duplicates:

```py
    # set up 2 unique rows and 1 duplicate
    rows = [
        ('book1', 'email@example.com', '10.25'),
        ('book2', 'email@example.com', '10.25'),
        ('book1', 'email@example.com', '10.25'),
    ]
    dataset = tablib.Dataset(*rows, headers=['name', 'author_email', 'price'])

    book_resource = _BookResource()
    result = book_resource.import_data(dataset)
    print(result.totals)
```

This gives the output:

```
OrderedDict([('new', 2), ('update', 0), ('delete', 0), ('skip', 1), ('error', 0), ('invalid', 0)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to skip the rows which is already present in the database. One way to do this is by comparing the particular field in the database with a column in the excel file.

So in this particular example, I am assuming that ig_username is a field in django model InstagramData and ig_username is also present in our excel file which I want to upload.
So in this particular example ig_username value in the excel get skipped if it is already present in the database. I have suffered a lot for this answer, I don't want you to be

```
    class InstagramResource(resources.ModelResource):
      def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        check=[]
        new=InstagramData.objects.all()
        for p in new:
            check.append(p.ig_username)
        if instance.ig_username in check:
            return True
        else:
            print("no")
            return False
      class Meta:
        model = InstagramData

  class InstagramDataAdminAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = InstagramResource
  admin.site.register(InstagramData,InstagramDataAdminAdmin)
```